# Django - TypeError: must be real number, not F (annotate)

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

I'm trying to create a method that returns a `QuerySet` or parcels with their distance from a given point (by LAT, LNG).

The problem is that it returns error:

```
@classmethod
def get_closest_parcels(cls, lat: decimal.Decimal, lng: decimal.Decimal, county=None) -> ParcelQuerySet:
    return Parcel.objects.annotate(distance=point_dist(lat, lng, F('lat'), F('lng')))
```

ERROR

```
geo.pyx in h3._cy.geo.point_dist()

TypeError: must be real number, not F
```

My goal is to find 5 closest parcels.

Do you know how can I do that using Django ORM?

Comment: `F()` is an expression(a SQL expression to be exact) not a value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions).

```
return Parcel.objects.annotate(distance=point_dist(..., ExpressionWrapper(F('lat'), output_field=DecimalField()) ,...))
```